# Why is this question a CW?

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

I was looking for questions about the terminal to see if there was a question similar to the question I had to ask, and I found a question that has been made a CW: [Listing the terminal commands available for Mac OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12645/list-of-terminal-commands-for-mac-os).

Why has the question been made a CW? as I read it, it asks for a command that list all the terminal commands, not for a list of commands available on the Mac OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List questions, such as [Terminal Tips and Tricks for Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/terminal-tips-and-tricks-for-mac-os-x) and [Mac OS X hidden features and nice tips & tricks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/mac-os-x-hidden-features-and-nice-tips-tricks) tend to be quite popular, and making them community wiki removes the incentive to gain massive reputation by creating one. It seems that the question you mention was mistaken for one of these types of questions - even the title seems to suggest that the author intended to create a list-type question.

However, upon reading the actual question, it's obvious that that was not the author's question at all, so I've unwiki'd the question and answers.

Comment: The title is a little confusing; when I first read it, I thought the question was asking for a list of all the terminal commands, and I read the answers just to see which commands they would list. I proposed a title edit for that question, trying to match it with what the question is really asking.

Answer (score 3):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.